# Primefaces bar chart tooltip

Tags: primefaces, tooltip, bar-chart, jqplot

I want to put a custom data in my barchart's tooltip.

I've tried to use Extender but I get only the values y ( x get column number):

[image]

I want like this : Date: 14-12-2017 (String format) instead of Date: 5

Code:

```
function chartExtender(){
            //this = chart widget instance
            //this.cfg = options
            this.cfg.grid = {
               background: '#FFF' //Set background to white
            };
            this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.showGridline = false;
            this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions.showGridline = false;
            this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString = '%s';
            this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions.formatString = '%d';
            this.cfg.series=[
                             { label : "line1",highlighter: {formatString: "<div><span> Date:  %s </span><br/><span>Nombre de notifications : %d</span></div>"} }
                            ],
            this.cfg.highlighter={show: true, useAxesFormatters: false, sizeAdjust: 25.5}
          }
```

Any help?

Comment: Does it work with other chart formats than bar-chart?

Comment: Does it work in plain jqplot?